# axes tickers not formatting correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

> **What specific changes need to be made to the code below in order for matplotlib to correctly 1.) show each year along the x-axis,
> and 2.) show meaningful numbers on the y-axis?**

**THE PROBLEM:**

The problem is that the code below causes the resulting matplotlib chart to 1.) give the x-axis tickers as 0 to 140+, and
2.) give the y-axis tickers as 0 to 1.0+ 1e7.

**WHAT WE NEED:**

x-axis: The quarterly data needs to be grouped annually along the x-axis.  This would mean the tickers show 1985, 1986, 1987,...

y-axis: The magnitude of the data need to be expressed either in all digits on the y-axis or in a format that reduces the number of significant figures to a specific number.

For example, all of the data points have values that are either 7 or 8 digits.  Instead of using exponential notation as the current chart does, we need the y-axis tickers to either round to 3 or 4 significant figures, or we need to print the entire
7 or 8 digits at rounded intervals such as 1000000, 1500000, ...

**DATA FORMAT:**

We have represented the quarters as follows:

```
q1 = yyyy-03-31
q2 = yyyy-06-30
q3 = yyyy-09-30
q4 = yyyy-12-31
```

When we run the test code as `python try1.py`, the `print(series.head())` command prints out the first rows as:

```
C:\path\to>python try1.py
  Time Period    Value
0  1985-03-31  1488501
1  1985-06-30  1518058
2  1985-09-30  1545168
3  1985-12-31  1577771
4  1986-03-31  1600514
```

**CURRENT CODE:**

The code in the `try1.py` file that we are currently using to produce the above UN-desired results is as follows:

```
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot

dataFileName = "some.csv"

series = read_csv(dataFileName, sep=',', header=0)
print(series.head())
series.plot()
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[datetime.date(1985, 12, 31), datetime.date(1986, 3, 31), datetime.date(1986, 6, 30), datetime.date(1987, 9, 30)],
                   'value':[1488501, 1518058, 1545168, 1577771]})

f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(df['date'], df['value'], marker = '.')

# format x axis
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))

# format y axis
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='plain')
```

result:

[image]

Comment: How do you suggest that we get from our `series = read_csv(dataFileName, sep=',', header=0)` into your `df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[datetime.date(1985, 12, 31), datetime.date(1986, 3, 31), datetime.date(1986, 6, 30), datetime.date(1987, 9, 30)], 'value':[1488501, 1518058, 1545168, 1577771]})` ?

Comment: simply do `df = series` or `df = read_csv(dataFileName, sep=',', header=0)`